# Did someone hack me?

Tags: iphone, wifi

I was on a public Wifi. When I returned home, reconnecting to my network, a panopli of numbers appeared on the network for 3 seconds. Then my network went after that. Going on google, I received a message saying that my iPhone was in danger, that someone was watching what I was doing. Is this a scam? Because I wasn’t on this page, I was on Time2Watch. I would like to have sincere answers please, I would not want to be spied on. Here are some pictures of the images that '' google or the scam '' sent me.

Thank you !!!

[image]

[image]

Comment: The website is a spam one. Please close it, go offline and clean all website data in the Safari Settings.

Comment: No, that's just a BS website. Just close it and move on, nothing else to do.

Comment: Any website you visit can see your IP address, thats how they connect in the first place! Above, I meant only this website's data. Don't flush everything.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii, I was speaking to OP. Your advice is good advice IMO.

Comment: @SamAndrew81 yes I too addressed OP. went to chatroom,  so couldn't edit it. It had a vote,  so didn't delete lol. guess I'd flag it duplicate

Comment: Thank you!!! I am reassured now! :)